# Row Level Security In oracle

Tags: security, oracle10g, row

I have a table ATM_Plan

```
CREATE TABLE ATM_PLAN
(
BRACNH          VARCHAR2(4) Primary Key, 
SAMITY_CODE     VARCHAR2(4),
SAMITY_NAME     VARCHAR2(30),
INT_CLS_MONTH   DATE,
TTL_MEMBER      NUMBER,
TTL_LONEE       NUMBER,
CM_TRG_DT       DATE,
ACT_CM_DT       DATE,
USER_CODE       VARCHAR2(5));
```

Sample Record

```
insert into ATM_PLAN (BRANCH, SAMITY_CODE) VALUES ('001', '20');
insert into ATM_PLAN (BRANCH, SAMITY_CODE) VALUES ('002', '20');
```

I have also developed a form for entry in this table. Multiple users will Insert record in this table. But I want to restrict to the entry, Specific users can entry on specific branch record only. 
As example branch 001 can not entry or update on branch 002 records.

I have 100 branches.

Is it Possible ? 
thanks in advance

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/apdvpoli.htm#CHDFGBEB) or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14267/intro.htm)?

Comment: Near about VPD. But how to apply on this table. Can you help me to clear this concept.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Read Alex's first link, esp. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/apdvpoli.htm#i1009600, for an intro to VPD. You can apply VPD policies to INSERT statements.